# Using Altair to create a merged chart with 3 charts but the first title is not aligning properly

Tags: python, altair

This is the chart I've created:

[image: 1]

But this is what I want it to look like:

[image: 2]

The title for "Top Third" is not centered where it should be but when I try to adjust the title alignment, I get an error that I can't use configuration with hconcat. This is the partial code for the visualization:

```
chart_top = (text_top + bars_top).properties(
    width=80,
    height=180,
    title="Top third",

)

chart_middle = (text_middle + bars_middle).properties(
    width=80,
    height=180,
    title="Middle third",


)

chart_bottom = (text_bottom + bars_bottom).properties(
    width=80,
    height=180,
    title="Bottom third",

)


merge = alt.hconcat(chart_top, chart_middle, chart_bottom).configure_scale(
    bandPaddingInner=0.2
).configure_view(
    strokeWidth=0
).properties(
    title={"text":["How People Rate the 'Star Wars' Movies"],
    "subtitle":["How often each film was rated in the top, middle and bottom third",
                '(by 471 respondents who have seen all six films)']}
).configure_title(
    fontSize=24, align='left', fontWeight='bold', anchor="start", subtitleFontWeight='lighter'
).configure_axis(
    labelFontSize=14)


alt.themes.enable('fivethirtyeight')

merge
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `alt.TitleParams` on the left most chart with either `dx` to manually set the offset or `anchor=end` to right align:

```
chart_top = (text_top + bars_top).properties(
    title=alt.TitleParams("Top third", dx=100))
```

You could also create an empty chart just holding the labels.